# Conditional regex to return empty string

Tags: java, regex

I need help with a conditional regex expression
What I need is: if the input contains a certain word return empty string, else extract the year

I have the regex

```
((?=AVOID))|(\d{4})(.*)
```

Examples:


For input: 
`TEST1 AVOID TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4`

`empty string` is extracted which is correct


For input: 
`TEST1 TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4`

`2016` is extracted which is ok


For input: 
`TEST1 TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4 AVOID`

`2016` is extracted which is not ok because `AVOID` is at the end of the input

Any help?

Comment: Is the year the *first* 4-digit chunk in your inputs? Or is it always in between spaces?

Comment: You're not looking for AVOID `OR` the year. You're looking for both. Replace the `|` by `.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?!.*\bAVOID\b).*?\b(\d{4})\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC6gC3/1)

This will extract the first 4-digit chunk that is a whole word if there is no `AVOID` as a whole word in a string.

If the 4 digits are always enclosed with spaces, use

```
/^(?!.*\bAVOID\b).*? (\d{4}) /
```

See an [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC6gC3/2) (when testing standalone strings, the space can be replaced with `\s`).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\bAVOID\b)` - a negative lookahead that checks if the line has a whole word `AVOID`, and if yes, returns no match (use DOTALL modifier to match across lines)
- `.*?` - 0+ any characters other than a newline (use DOTALL modifier to match across lines)
- `\b(\d{4})\b` - any 4 digits that are a whole word.

**NOTE**: `.*?` will match as few characters as possible before the first 4-digit whole word chunk (because of the reluctant quantifier `*?`). If you need to get the last 4-digit whole word chunk, use a greedy counterpart `.*`. You may further experiment with specifying the context around `\d{4}`.

See [**Java demo**](http://ideone.com/I1tnJs)

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("TEST1 AVOID TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4", "TEST1 TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4", "TEST1 TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4 AVOID");
String pat = "^(?!.*\\bAVOID\\b).*?\\b(\\d{4})\\b";
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(str);  
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));   // return m.group(1)
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match for " + str + " :("); // return "" here
    }
}
```

Results:

```
No match for TEST1 AVOID TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4 :(
2016
No match for TEST1 TEST2 2016 TEST3 TEST4 AVOID :(
```

Comment: Just forgot to add that `.*?` will match as few characters as possible before the *first* 4-digit whole word chunk (because of the reluctant quantifier `*?`). If you need to get the last 4-digit whole word chunk, use a greedy counterpart `.*`. You mau further experiment with specifying the context around `\d{4}`.

Comment: Ok so now I see that it doesn't return empty string if the pattern doesn't match..Can you take a look?

Comment: @dres: Please `return` an empty value from the `else` block. See my comments in the sample code.

Comment: can't this be done throgh the regex? I would't want to add code

Comment: I need the final output in a group, for example if it matches then return the year, else return empty string. Directly from the regex. That;s why the title is `conditional regex` ..

Comment: "Conditional" in the title is ambiguous. What you cannot do with regex (and Java regex does not support [*conditional construct*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)), you can always make up for with code. You want to get an empty `group(1)` if the word `AVOID` is present in the *string*? You can't but rely on some code logic. Let me put it straight: **it is impossible to make Group 1 contain an empty string if the word `AVOID` is present somewhere in the string**.